# Magento 2 Reviews menu not showing backend and frontend

Tags: magento2

I have disabled magento 2 reviews module on Magento 2.2 with `bin/magento module:disable Magento_Review` command and removed with composer.

Now i want to use this module again i have installed it with composer and enabled it.
It's showing installed and enabled with `bin/magento module:status` command.
But there nothing showing on frontend and backend.

Also i checked source files of review module under vendor module there is no problem too.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: you check this file module enable or not `app/etc/config.php`

Comment: It's enabled i checked it already

Answer (score 0):

1) rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;

2) php bin/magento setup:upgrade

3) php bin/magento setup:di:compile

4) php bin/magento s:s:d -f

5) php bin/magento c:f

6) php bin/magento c:c

Let me know how it goes.

Thanks, Sam

Comment: It doesn't work